# div with overflow on the left and left aligned showing the end of the text

Tags: css, html, text, overflow

trying to set up css doing the following:

Imagine we have two equal parallel divs with text in it:

```
<div class="xy">Example</div>
<div class="xy">This.is.a.example.of.a.long.Text</div>
```

The divs are wider than "Example" but less wide than "This.is.a.example.of.a.long.Text".
Now I want to see these texts left-aligned, so that the odd space is behind "Example" on the ride side.

But i also want to use

```
text-overflow:ellipsis
```

with the longer text in a way that I will see the **end of the text**.
So it should look like:

```
"Example                "
"...ample.of.a.long.Text"
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You can't ellipsis from the left AFAIK...perhaps RTL/LTR nut that's gonna mess up your text.

Comment: yeah i tried rtl but that does not give me the result!

Comment: can you use javascript on your project?

Comment: Yes I can use Javascript!

Answer (score 0):

I was just curious to your question and give it a try in java script as follows,

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qJJ99/)**

```
var maxChar = 20,
    dots = '. . . ',
    toTrim = $('.toTrim'),
    toTrimLength = toTrim.text().length,
    getChar = toTrimLength - maxChar;

if(toTrimLength > maxChar){
    var newString = dots + toTrim.text().slice(getChar)    
    toTrim.text(newString);
}
```

I guess you still need to modify this to  suite your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Also add the same string in title attr to see full text when hovering and if you want to do it even better. change text-overflow on :hover

this article will help you http://html5hub.com/ellipse-my-text/#i.6k1nyg11zqdiar